# Manually Lock a Single Table Row

Tags: php, mysql

I've locked entire tables before in MySQL but what I need to do is lock a specific row. More specifically, when my PHP script executes, I need it to Lock a specific row so it cannot be read from (or written to), run the rest of the code, then unlock the row when it's finished.

I know I need to use InnoDB for this, but I've been unable to find how to do this. I'm not sure if it requires transactions or not, and if so, how to use them for row level locking.

**Update**

Perhaps I'm thinking of this problem the wrong way. From the reading I've done, and been provided with, InnoDB tables auto lock rows when read/written, which I get. My concern though is that I want to introduce a delay in my PHP code via a `sleep`. I want any and all read attempts on the row that was previously read from to be locked until that sleep finishes, and the script finishes the rest of it's functions.

If I just run:

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare('...');
$result->bind_param('...', $...);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($...);
$result->fetch();
sleep('15');
//More script execution
$result->close();
```

Will that prevent other MySQL queries from accessing that selected row until I close the connection?

Comment: check out this so thread: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/innodb-row-locking-how-to-implement

Comment: @John That seems awfully complicated for a row lock

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL uses only table-level locking from MyISAM tables.`For row-leve locking you would need to switch to `innoDB`.

Please see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) which tells about the lock functioning in mysql.

Comment: I am using InnoDB, I mention that in my question. My problem is from that documentation I don't know how to enforce a read/write lock on a row when using a `SELECT`...

Comment: check internal locking method http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html

Comment: I only see the code for `LOCK TABLES`, which I've used in the past. In the  section for row locking it only mentions row locking with specific queries, it doesn't show anything like `LOCK ROW table WHERE x = y` Which leads me to believe I'm approaching this wrong.